# Concurrency in AWS RDS (from multiple Rails applications)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Currently I have running two Rails applications on different servers. One application is back end scrapers which is fetching data and saving it to shared database(AWS RDS). The second app is front end which is fetching data from shared DB and showing results to users.

My question is:

I want to scale up my back end app by running it on multiple EC2 instances to speed up scraping speed.

- Can I write to my database from multiple rails applications
  simultaneously without having any concurrency issues ?
- Will it effect database writing speed ?
- Is there a better solution e.g scaling up my single server(Personally I don't think it will increase scraping performance)

Comment: I think there's very little information to provide you with an answer. In my experience, the app that is fetching data is usually IO bound to the source of the data, so it won't be maxing out RDS in any way (unless something really crazy goes on the DB, like really complex functions/stored procedures). My suggestion would be: give it a try...

Comment: Yes I am going to give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can write to your database from multiple servers. If you are updating the same records from multiple threads then you might have to use database transactions, but it doesn't sound like you are doing that.

In general, the number of CPU cores on the database server, and the server's disk speed will affect how many concurrent inserts your database can handle. First, you definitely want to use an SSD backed database instance. Next you want to slowly ramp up the number of servers you have writing to the database, while monitoring the CPU, memory, and IOPS on the RDS server. You can monitor these metrics directly from the RDS console or the CloudWatch console.

If the CPU or memory start becoming a bottleneck you will need to increase the size of your server (or scale out to multiple database servers). If the disk IO becomes a bottleneck you can either increase the size of the provisioned SSD volume to get a higher baseline IOPS (with the added benefit of getting more available space), or directly provision IOPS (can be expensive).

Comment: Thanks @mbaird for such a great answer.